# Spring @Secured and @PreAuthorize have no effect in plain (non-web) application

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I created a `Application` Spring component with two secured methods:

```
@Component
public class Application {

    public void run() {
        onlyAdminMethod();
        onlyAdminMethod2();
    }

    @Secured( "ROLE_ADMIN" )
    public void onlyAdminMethod() {
        System.out.println( "Admin-only method called" );
    }

    @PreAuthorize( "hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" )
    public void onlyAdminMethod2() {
        System.out.println( "Admin-only method 2 called" );
    }
}
```

I call `run()` method on that bean, which I take from Spring XML context:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
     new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");  
context.getBean( Application.class).run();
```

**Nothings happen - methods are called normally** even if there is no authentication and `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns `null`

**My Spring XML**:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="practice" />

<security:authentication-manager>
   <security:authentication-provider>
      <security:user-service>
         <security:user name="admin" password="stackoverflow" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
      </security:user-service>
   </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

I use Maven dependencies for `Spring 3.2.4`

Comment: Spring uses a proxy based solution for AOP. Which means only external method calls are intercepted, you are making internal method calls and those bypass the proxy.

Comment: @M.Deinum Unfortunatelly, after extracting those 2 methods to `@Service MyService` class and adding it as `@Autowired` I can still call both `myService` method without any interruption.

Comment: make sure you are also using class based proxies (you aren't using interfaces so JDK Dynamic Proxies won't work). Add `proxy-target-class="true"` to your `global-method-security` element. Make sure you also have cglib on your classpath as that is required for classbased proxies.

Comment: @M.Deinum will check it tomorrow, post as answer if it helps, I will accept.

Comment: @M.Deinum works well, so I will accept your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 Things

Spring uses a proxy based solution for AOP. Which means only external method calls are intercepted, you are making internal method calls and those bypass the proxy.

Second make sure you are using class based proxies (you aren't using interfaces so JDK Dynamic Proxies won't work). Add `proxy-target-class="true"` to your `<global-method-security .. />` element. Make sure you have cglib on your classpath as that is required for classbased proxies.