# Spring Security: @PreAuthorize works only together with @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-annotations

I have a Spring MVC controller and want to secure it with Spring Method Security.
In the following example **it works** - `@RequestMapping`and `@PreAuthorize`annotate the same method:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {  
        return test(request, response);
    }

    public ModelAndView test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
```

In this example **it does not work** - `@RequestMapping`and `@PreAuthorize`annotate different methods:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {  
        return test(request, response);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public ModelAndView test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
```

What might be the reason for this strange behaviour?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19421786/1291150

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second example the `test` method is being called directly from the `handleRequest` method.  Spring has no mechanism to intercept method calls from with in the same class.  Thus, the Proxy / AOP method inception for `@PreAutorize` is never invoked.

[More on the topic of Spring Proxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)

Comment: Thank you - great answer, that helps!!! I only wonder, why this is not mentioned anywhere in tutorials, when `@PreAuthorize` is described. :|  How good, that there are experts on stackoverflow.

Comment: @olivmir There is a necessary degree of assumed knowledge about how Spring works in most of the Spring documentation.  If the documentation attempted to describe a feature with out this assumed knowledge, or in the context of how Spring works, then the docs would be very messy and repetitive.